# zf2 do not recognize the jquery library

Tags: zend-framework2

this is the Lyout code

```
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <?php echo $this->headScript()
        ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js')
        ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.min.js')                
        ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery-ui.js')
        ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery-1.8.3.js')
        ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.min.js')
        ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/respond.min.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',))
        ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/html5shiv.js',   'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',))
```

So the problem is easy i cant work with dialog and other jquery effects however
using the url i can , please where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because you're prepending all the script which means the scripts will be added in reverse order. Try using appendFile:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<?php echo $this->headScript()
    ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.min.js')                
    ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery-ui.js')
    ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/respond.min.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',))
    ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/html5shiv.js',   'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',))
```

You were also including jquery multiple times.

Comment: That's not the real problem, the solution is offered
Mohammad Zeineddin

Answer (score 0):

There is some conflicts and compatibility problems between Bootstrap and some other libraries like jQuery UI ... so it is better to use one of them or solve these conflicts between the two libraries on your own.
Also you need to include the libraries one time only, the file with the name "min" means that the file is minified (smaller in size) which is more efficient to use.

Comment: so the real problem is the js                                    Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui.js:315
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'